# How to release a mutable borrow after method call which takes mutable reference to self?

Tags: rust, methods, reference, mutable, borrow

How can I call an objects method which takes a mutable reference to self, without moving the object into the method scope?

The following code shows a very simple struct, which has two attributes 1) a vector of ints 2) a vector of optional references to those ints:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    vec: Vec<i32>,
    ref_vec: Vec<&'a i32>
}
impl <'a> MyStruct <'a>{
    fn new() -> MyStruct<'a>{
        MyStruct{
            vec: Vec::new(),
            ref_vec: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add_int(&'a mut self, value: i32, reference: bool){
        self.vec.push(value);
        let n = self.vec.len();
        
        if reference == true {
            self.ref_vec.push(&self.vec[n-1])
        }
    }

}


fn main() {
    let mut v = MyStruct::new();

    v.add_int(55, true);

    println!("Added element is {}", v.ref_vec[0])
}
```

What I would like it to do is to add `55` to `v.vec` and to add a reference to `v.vec[0]` to `v.ref_vec`.

It **does** do this, but in doing so `v` is borrowed by `add_int` (even though `add_int` only takes a mutable reference to `self`), and thus `v.ref_vec[0]` is not able to perform the required borrow in the final line.

output:

```bash
  --> src/main.rs:30:37
   |
28 |     v.add_int(55, true);
   |     ------------------- mutable borrow occurs here
29 |
30 |     println!("Added element is {}", v.ref_vec[0])
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^
   |                                     |
   |                                     immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                     mutable borrow later used here
```

How can I call the method `add_int` without losing the ability to reference it later?